# Any experience with Current Sensor TLI4971

Tags: current, sensor, current-limiting

I'm looking to include current overload protection for a new application and wondering if anybody has experience with Infineon's range of TLI4971 devices. [Datasheet here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLI4971_25_50_75_120-DataSheet-v01_20-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462700c0ae6017034d731621b09#:%7E:text=TLI4971%20is%20a%20high%20precision,fast%20over-current%20detection%20outputs)
I like the fast over-current open drain outputs, and the small form factor.  Downsides are the configuration via programming (adds complexity) and the low sensitivity (48mV/A for the 25A part).

My initial design was going to use AKM CZA3xx devices, but their form factor is larger, although with better sensitivity and programming via a reference voltage.

Comment: I see that mikro electronica have this as an add in prototyping board "current sensor 8". I might buy one of these and connect a micro controller.  But I'm still interested in real world experience before I invest too much time and effort.

Comment: No experience with this specific IC BUT a common point to watch. Be absolutely certain that any overload current will not overload the current shunt to the point of thermal destruction. If this happens isolation may be lost and your low voltage electronics may be destoyed.

Comment: Infineon provide a C++/Arduino interface library [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/tli4971-current-sensor/) . Probably the same but for completeness [here](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/tli4971-current-sensor).

Comment: Thanks Russel - I'll take a look at the Arduino library first as the mikroE one only supports their compilers.